# Azure text to speech and play it in virtual microphone using python

Tags: python, azure, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

My use case is to convert text to speech using Azure and then play it into a virtual microphone.

## option 1 - with an intermediate .wav file

I tried both steps manually on a Jupiter notebook. 
The problem is, the output .wav file of Azure cannot be played directly on the python
"error: No file 'file.wav' found in working directory". When I restart the python kernal, audio can be played.

#### text-to-speech

```
audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioOutputConfig(filename="file.wav")
...
speech_synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
speech_synthesis_result = speech_synthesizer.speak_text_async(text).get()
```

#### audio play

```
mixer.init(devicename = 'Line 1 (Virtual Audio Cable)')
mixer.music.load("file.wav")
mixer.music.play()
```

## option 2 - direct stream to audio device

I tried to configure the audio output device of azure SDK.
this method worked for output devices. but when I add an ID of the virtual microphone, it won't play any sound.

```
audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioOutputConfig(use_default_speaker=False,device_name="{0.0.0.00000000}.{9D30BDBF-1418-4AFC-A709-CD4C431833E2}")
```

#### Also it will be much better if there is any other method that can direct the audio to a virtual microphone instead of the speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by changing the output a stream, saving to a file and then play it through pygame as follows,

```
speech_synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=None)
speech_synthesis_result = speech_synthesizer.speak_text_async(text).get()
stream = speechsdk.AudioDataStream(speech_synthesis_result)
stream.save_to_wav_file("file.wav")

mixer.init(devicename = 'Line 1 (Virtual Audio Cable)')
mixer.music.load("file.wav")
mixer.music.play()
```

Also much appreciated if there is any other method that doesn't need any intermediate audio file.

Comment: If you want to stream synthesized audio data directly to some playback input without saving the data to file, you can take a look at PushAudioOutputStream configuration for SpeechSynthesizer, which provides application callback with the data buffer
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/python/console/speech_synthesis_sample.py#L253

Answer (score 0):

Create a speech service and get the key and location of the service.

[image]

Then set the environment with that key. Open command prompt and use the below code block.

```
setx SPEECH_KEY yourkey
```

Use `import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk`

After conversion, use the below code block to get the virtual device.

```
audio_config = AudioConfig(device_name="<device id>");
```

Get the device speaker information and set it in this location.

Comment: I got the ID of the virtual microphone, then, <br>
I tried this, but It just played on my default speaker. 
`audio_config = speechsdk.AudioConfig(device_name="{0.0.1.00000000}.{b0fbce64-ced2-4233-bb72-346d732c5930}", use_default_microphone=False) `
 
bellow code didn't play anything, but code executed successfully. 
`audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioOutputConfig(use_default_speaker=False,device_name="{0.0.1.00000000}.{b0fbce64-ced2-4233-bb72-346d732c5930}") `

Comment: only output devices IDs are working for above codes.

Comment: In playback settings of the device which the code is being executed, check whether any virtual device configuration settings are mismatched or not. It worked for me. Check the device configuration once.

Comment: Is the device you tried an input or output virtual device?